# android holder.getChildAt issue

Tags: android, adapter, listadapter

I am working with a list adapter and I am trying to set it up so that when an item in a listview is clicked on a reaction occurs (setting an overlay item to visible within the item selected), what I am trying to do is make the item previously clicked invisible when another item is clicked. The problem is I am getting the following crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lists.MainAdapter$1.onClick(MainAdapter.java:106)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17126)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it is occurring with the following code:

```
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("image click");
                holder.grid_overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(!(lastView == 0)){
                    View item = holder.grid_overlay.getChildAt(lastView);
                    if(item.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    System.out.println("before update "+lastView);
                }

                lastView = Integer.valueOf(holder.encase.getTag().toString());
                System.out.println("after update "+lastView);
            }
        });
```

the problem seems to point to the following line:

```
if(item.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
```

could someone please help. 
thanks :)

Comment: what is the holder variable?

Comment: holder is a view holder within a list adapter